# Finding the number of ways we can arrange numbers under conditional repetition.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Here, a certain range of numbers are given eg, 0 to 5. The task is to find number of 4-digit numbers we can make from the given range (inclusive). Repetition of a number is only allowed to be within two or less.

Eg:

For range 0 to 1 :- 
1101, 1000, 1011, 0000 etc are invalid and 1100, 1001,0101,1010 etc are valid (leading zeroes are allowed).

For range 3 to 6 :-
3334, 5565, 4444, 6656 etc are invalid and 3456, 3356, 4456 etc are valid.

For given range 0 to 1, number of ways is 6.

Can someone help me by providing a formula to handle this kind of problem?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $k$ digits, with number of repetitions allowed $<3$, we can subtract from total possibilities, number of 3-repetitions and 4-repetitions.

Total 4-digit numbers $= k^4$

# of 3-repetitions $= k\cdot1\cdot1\cdot(k-1)\cdot\binom{4}{1}$

# of 4-repetitions $= k$

Required answer $= \boxed{k^4-4k^2+3k}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let the range have $n$ numbers denoted by $x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n$ and $k-$digit numbers(your problem is for $k=4$), then what you want is to keep track of how many have element have you place of each digit, call this number $y_i$ for $x_i$ and so your expressions is
$$\sum _{\substack{y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_n=k\\0\leq y_i\leq 2}}\frac{k!}{y_1!\cdots y_n!}.$$

For the special case $k=4$ we can do case work as:

1. $2+2=4$ then $\binom{n}{2}\frac{4!}{4}=3\cdot n(n-1).$
2. $1+1+2=4$ then $\binom{n}{2}(n-2)\frac{4!}{2}=6\cdot n(n-1)(n-2).$
3. $1+1+1+1=4$ then $4!$

So we get $$[n>1]3\cdot n(n-1)+[n>2]6\cdot n(n-1)(n-2)+[n>3]24,$$ where $[n>i]$ is the Iverson bracket meaning is $1$ if the proposition is true and $0$ otherwise. For example, then for $n=2$ we have $6$ and for $n=4$ we get $36+144+24=204.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.